# App Engine Firebase Authentication UI Widget Issue

Tags: html, python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, firebase-authentication

I have developed an app on Google App Engine in Python37 & Flask on the Standard Environment. I have the following file as the index.html for authentication. I have configured the Firebase authentication app to include Google, Email and Facebook authentication. However, the widget only shows Google and Email. None of the other implementations of the Firebase Authentication-UI returns the Token that can be verified in python main.py app.

index.html - I have the correct Firebase config values in my real html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="/static/all.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
          apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
          authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
          storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "<MESSAGING_SENDER_ID>"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
  <script>
    if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') {
      const msg = "Please paste the Firebase initialization snippet into index.html. See https://console.firebase.google.com > Overview > Add Firebase to your web app.";
      console.log(msg);
      alert(msg);
    }
  </script>
  <!-- [START gae_python37_auth_include_firebaseui] -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.6.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.6.2/firebaseui.css">
  <!-- [END gae_python37_auth_include_firebaseui] -->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

</head>
<body>

  <br><br><br>
  <div class="title is-4 has-text-centered">
    <div>
        Welcome to Myapp
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title is-5 has-text-centered">Myapp</div>

<!-- [START gae_python37_auth_firebase_html] -->
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>

<button id="sign-out" hidden=true>Sing out</button>

<div id="login-info" hidden=true>

</div>
<!-- [END gae_python37_auth_firebase_html] -->

<!-- Footer Section -->

</body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
claims = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(
     id_token, firebase_request_adapter)
```

See below the implementation I did as per [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui#oauth_providers_google_facebook_twitter_and_github) that @Ajordat has referred to. I get a an empty id_token error - *Illegal ID token provided: None. ID token must be a non-empty string*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGZGu.png)

Here is the index.html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
          apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
          authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
          storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "<MESSAGING_SENDER_ID>"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>


  <script>
  var uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
        // User successfully signed in.
        // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
        // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
        return true;
      },
      uiShown: function() {
        // The widget is rendered.
        // Hide the loader.
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
      }
    },
    // Will use popup for IDP Providers sign-in flow instead of the default, redirect.
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl: '/',
    signInOptions: [
      // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
    // Privacy policy url.
    privacyPolicyUrl: '<your-privacy-policy-url>'
  };

  // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</h1>

<!-- [START gae_python37_auth_firebase_html] -->
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>

<button id="sign-out" hidden=true>Sign Out</button>

<div id="login-info" hidden=true>
  <h2>Login info:</h2>
  {% if user_data %}
    <dl>
      <dt>Name</dt><dd>{{ user_data['name'] }}</dd>
      <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{ user_data['email'] }}</dd>
      <dt>Last 10 visits</dt><dd>
    {% for time in times %}
          <p>{{ time['timestamp'] }}</p>
        {% endfor %} </dd>
    </dl>
  {% elif error_message %}
    <p>Error: {{ error_message }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>

User id :{{ uid }}
<br>
User: {{ user.email }}
<br>
Error: {{ error_message }}
<br><br><br>
{{ id_token }}

<!-- [END gae_python37_auth_firebase_html] -->
</body>
</html>
```

The main.py code for verifying the id_token

```
...
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

@app.route('/')
def root():
    # Verify Firebase auth.
    id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
    error_message = ''
    uid = None
    user = None

    # if id_token:
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
        user = auth.get_user(uid)
    except ValueError as exc:
        error_message = str(exc)

    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        uid=uid, user=user, error_message = error_message)
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand your workflow, have you followed [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui#oauth_providers_google_facebook_twitter_and_github) or another guide? if the latter, I would like to know which one so I can further investigate. If you have more code auth-related it may prove helpful to share it.

Comment: Hi @Ajordat , Yes I did. The implementation using the CDN in the document brings up the widget, but after a successful sign-in it does not create an id_token on the browser so that it can be verified on the server side via python. The only widget that does return an id_token is the one above (CDN - .../2.6.2/firebaseui.js). But, it does not give the Facebook auth option even though I have enabled it on the Firebase Authentication App.

Comment: From what I can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl) about the callback `signInSuccessWithAuthResult`, you can retrieve the token from the parameter `authResult` as it will have [this signature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential). You will be in charge of sending the value you want to the server.

Comment: Thank you @Ajordat . It worked. I used both `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` and `onAuthStateChanged` to set a cookie with id_token which I then read through the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to get the token from `authResult.user` and set it as a cookie so it can later be retrieved from the server. See the code attached:

```js
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
    var user = authResult.user;
    var credential = authResult.credential;
    var isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
    var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
    var operationType = authResult.operationType;
    if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then(function (accessToken) {
            console.log("token retrieved: " + accessToken);
            document.cookie = "token=" + accessToken + "; samesite=Lax";
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```